# How to fit any size image in fixed size view in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to fit my image with fix size of view, border radius and borderWidth in react-native

```
 <CachedImage
resizeMode="contain"
source={{
    uri:
        "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bracketopia-storage/products/logo_fresh.jpg"
}}
style={{
    height: 100,
    width: 180,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: "hidden",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: AppColors.grey
}}
/>;
```

but I am not able to achieve it I am getting somthing like :

[image]

Comment: properties like overflow and alignItems are View properties. not for Image

Comment: we need to use overflow='hidden' to show images with borderRadius. If u have any better idea please share to show images with roudRadius. Here alignItems we can remove.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove resizeMode="contain" properties

`resizemode` will resize your image as you pass param here you are passing `contain` as param then contain will cale the image both dimensions and also cale the corresponding dimension of the view and set the image as in View by based on its aspect ratio.

For more details please check react native document :
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode